# Facing error after changing password of database password in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a magento store. For security reason i had to change the password of database in cPanel. After changing the password i have updated the password in /app/etc/local.xml file. But still its giving the below error.
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 873381675548
In the error log file its saying database connection error. But I am unable to trace where is the database file except /app/etc/local.xml.

Please help..

Comment: Do you have any other .xml files in app/etc?  Magento globs all those *.xml files together, so if you did something like make `old_local.xml` as a temporary backup it would still be getting read.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have cache enabled. As cache has existing credentials saved, login is denied
Though changes new on local.xml. Since you can not login to admin (i assume), try below:

1. Delete all files and folders under  [your-magento-root]/var/cache (rm -rf var/cache/* if are in root folder of your magento installation.

Sometimes it happens that you mistype the password. Try to login using same password from other MySQL client (PhpMyAdmin, shell etc) to check whether password is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the mistake was in myside. There was a backup file of .xml in that server. And thats why password was not updating.